# Understanding terraform provider and plugin

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Is there a simpler way to understand them ? When I use a provider in my code and do a `terraform init` - does it download a provider or plugin ?

Where are and what are the 3rd party plugins ? Is is same as 3rd party provider like that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plugins is how you **develop providers**. For example, `AWS` provider is  implemented as a plugin in `go` programming language into terraform.

The source code of the `AWS` provider plugin is [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws):

> The Terraform AWS provider is a **plugin for Terraform** that allows for the full lifecycle management of AWS resources.

So, as an end-user you are using `AWS` provider. But if you want to contribute to the provider, and implement or fix bugs in it, you will be doing this in in a context of a plugin in `go` language.

> When I use a provider in my code and do a terraform init - does it download a provider or plugin ?

Technically it downloads a plugin that provides the `AWS` (example) provider functionality. It will be stored in your project's directory in **plugins folder**:

```
.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v3.2.0_x5
```

> 3rd party provider

This is a provider **not distributed** by HashiCorp. Those third-party providers/plugins are "manually" installed in the plugins folder, whereas those by  HashiCorp are installed using `terraform init`.